# How to edit and test a gem I forked?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I know that I can specify the location of the gem in a GEMFILE but what if I don't want to use a dummy rails app? (or if I did use a dummy rails app how would I do this?) Essentially, what if I wanted to do the the equivalent of `gem install 'foo'` but the gem was something I forked from  GitHub and that I have edited myself. Also, there is no .gem file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `.gem` file you can run `gem install --force --local GEM_NAME.gem`

Without a .gem file, you can build your gem with a gemspec: `gem build GEM_NAME.gemspec`

If you don't have a gemspec file, then write one or use [bundler to maintain one](http://bundler.io/v1.8/rubygems.html)

Your .gem file is just an archived file of the gem itself.

Comment: Thank you so much! I also found [this resource](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#your-first-gem) with a similar solution.